# Is it possible to only allow authenticated users to use callable function, without getting billed for invalid invocations?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a callable function that gets users auth data and validates it (inside the function), if user is not authenticated or allowed to do a certain action I throw respective error.

However nothing stops malicious actors to run a loop that constantly pings such function and rack up cost in terms of invocations / little bit of time those functions run.

Cloud providers like AWS have systems in place where this auth check is set up on an api gateway / loadbalancer level and users are not billed if someone calls functions with unexpected headers / payload or without authentication.

Does something like this exist for firebase, perhaps via google cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  The callable function must execute in order for the firebase-functions SDK to verify the user's ID token via the Firebase Admin SDK.  It's not a "free" operation in any way.  No matter how you write or deploy it, something is going to have to invoke the Firebase Admin SDK to verify the token - it's not part of any unbilled cloud infrastructure.