# How to secure a Firebase backend when it interacts with a MV3 Chrome extension? (AppCheck, Auth, ...)

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, content-security-policy, firebase-app-check

To protect myself and my project from fraud and abuse (especially since Firebase billing does not allow a hard limit) I would really like to protect the Cloud Function endpoints with AppCheck. The issue is, however, that there is a Chrome extension involved in this project, which calls a Callable Cloud Function.

I tried using the Firebase AppCheck library `appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(...), ...})` but it it loads external scripts and that is not allowed with the Content Security Policy of manifest V3.  As also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71963890/how-to-use-recaptcha-v3-in-chrome-extension) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421816/how-do-i-display-google-recaptcha-v2-in-a-chrome-extension-browser-action/56332614#56332614), it's not really possible to load reCAPTCHA in an manifest V3 extension (I only need it in the popup, not the content).

The extension requires users to authenticate with a Google account to be used but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64382133/18567120) (see comments, I'm wondering the same) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326681/is-it-possible-to-only-allow-authenticated-users-to-use-callable-function-witho) post suggest that user authentication can only be checked within the Callable function, meaning the function will get invoked. So no option either.

So is there **any** option at all when using Firebase with a Chrome extension to protect myself from a malicious actor attacking the endpoints and creating an enormous bill for me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after quite some hours I might have figured out a way. But would be helpful if someone more knowledgeable could confirm.

The solution is to create a custom AppCheck token ([docs](https://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-provider)) which is then passed along with the custom claims of the Firebase user auth object.

Only this allows to close down all Cloud Function endpoints as in other scenarios a client token is always fetched from a server, which then leads back to having an open endpoint somewhere.

The token then needs to be refreshed by a scheduled periodic function and attached to the custom claims. So when a user signs in on the browser extension, they always obtain a valid AppCheck token along with their id_token.

On the backend it would look like this:

```
const appCheckTokenResult = await appCheck.createToken(appId, { ttlMillis: someExpiration);
const appCheckToken = appCheckTokenResult.token;
const appCheckTokenExpiration = appCheckTokenResult.ttlMillis / 1000;

await auth.setCustomUserClaims(uid, {
  appCheckToken: appCheckToken,
  appCheckTokenExpiration: appCheckTokenExpiration,
});
```

The AppCheck provider is not shared between popup and background, so it needs to be initialized in boths contexts. On the extension client it would look like this:

```
const appCheckCustomProvider = new CustomProvider({
  getToken: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
      const appCheckToken = {
        token: appCheckToken, //from custom claims
        expireTimeMillis: appCheckTokenExpiration, //from custom claims
      }

      resolve(appCheckToken)
    })
  },
})

appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
  provider: appCheckCustomProvider,
})
```